# Please help me " java Exception in thread main java.lang.nullpointerexception"

Tags: java

I would like to ask help for my project. I am a newbie programmer and I don't get this error **`"exception in thread main java.lang.nullpointerexception"`**

this is my code:

```
 public class Slumbook{

    public String codeName;

    public Slumbook(){
        //
    }

    public Slumbook(String codeName){
        this.codeName = codeName;
    }

    public String getCodeName(){return codeName;}

    public void setCodeName(String codeName){this.codeName = codeName;}
   }
```

And the **`Driver Program`** code is:-

```
import java.util.*;

public class SlumbookD{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        Slumbook[] slum = new Slumbook[20];

        for(int n=0; n<10; n++){
            slum[n].setCodeName(sc.nextLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You create an array, but never intialize the each array slot. You should look into what a `NullPointerException` is, because this question gets asked ALL THE TIME.

Comment: By the time you get to the loop,  `slum[n]` has not been instantiated; that is, it is a null reference/pointer.  To fix, instantiate each element in `slum` before attempting to set its code name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize the Array elements before using them.

```
Slumbook[] slum = new Slumbook[20];

for(int n=0; n<10; n++){
    slum[n] = new Slumbook();
    slum[n].setCodeName(sc.nextLine());
}
```

You can initialize all the elements of array at once to avoid any future Exceptions

```
Slumbook[] slum = new Slumbook[20];

for(int i = 0 ; i < slum.length ; i++)  //initializing all the elements
    slum[i] = new Slumbook();

for(int n=0; n<10; n++){
    slum[n].setCodeName(sc.nextLine());
}
```

Comment: I think it's more overhead to have two for loops, and can you **explain** which future exception will come?

Answer (score 1):

You allocated the array ... but you failed to allocate any objects contained in the array.

SUGGESTION:

```
import java.util.*;

public class SlumbookD { 

    public static void main(String[] args){
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Slumbook[] slum = new Slumbook[20];
      for(int n=0; n<slum.length; n++){
          slum[n] = new Slumbook(sc.nextLine);
      }
    }

}
```

... OR BETTER ...

```
// You only need one class - with it's own main().  Not two classes...
public class Slumbook{

  public String codeName;

  public Slumbook(String codeName){
    this.codeName = codeName;
  }

  public String getCodeName(){
    return codeName;
  }

  public void setCodeName(String codeName){
    this.codeName = codeName;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    Slumbook[] slum = new Slumbook[20];
    for(int n=0; n<slum.length; n++){
        slum[n] = new Slumbook(sc.nextLine);
    }
  }
```

}

Comment: Type slowly... too many typos.

Comment: @ ambigram_maker: Because the OP named his "driver class" SlumbookD.

Comment: Yeah, I get it... but that's no excuse for `getCodeNae()` ;-)

Comment: @Remarc Balisi - my pleasure. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

You have created blank array but not initialize it, you have to associate object reference at your array index and *then you can call any number of setter methods on that index*.

```
 Slumbook[] slum = new Slumbook[20];

    for(int n=0; n<10; n++){
        slum[n] = new Slumbook(); //  Instantiate Slumbook class and assign reference
        slum[n].setCodeName(sc.nextLine());
    }
```